# How to get country code from country name using react-native-phone-number-input?

Tags: react-native

I want to set the `defaultCode` prop of the `PhoneInput` to the country code of the country which i get from  my reducer `userReducer.country` that returns for example "UNITED STATES". My solution is :

```
    switch(userReducer.country):
       case("UNITED STATES"):
           return "US";
       ...
```

how to use another alternative using the `getCountryCode` function in the [React Native Phone Number Input](https://github.com/garganurag893/react-native-phone-number-input#methods) ?

Answer (score 3):

```
const phoneInput = useRef<PhoneInput>(null);

console.log(phoneInput.current?.getCallingCode());

  <PhoneInput
              ref={phoneInput}
              .....
  />
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Is the code for the getting country calling code for example for US +1 , this code will return you the calling code for concat with the mobile number

Answer (score 0):

I think as it uses [google-libphonenumber](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber) it can detect the current country using `.getCallingCode()` and `.getCountryCode()`

```
const phoneInput = useRef<PhoneInput>(null); 

console.log(phoneInput.current?.getCallingCode());

<PhoneInput
   ref={phoneInput}
   .....
/>
```